# Localizing Helpshift iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization, helpshift

I want to use the localized version of Helpshift but it always seems to be appearing in English. How do I get it to work?

This is how I show the corresponding viewcontrollers at the moment:

```
case .FAQ:
    HelpshiftSupport.showFAQs(self, withOptions: nil)
case .ContactUs:
    HelpshiftSupport.showConversation(self, withOptions: nil)
```

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To have Helpshift localized into the device language, make sure you have integrated the HSLocalization folder with your Xcode project.
Helpshift comes with [built in support for 45 languages](https://developers.helpshift.com/ios/i18n/#i18n).
If you want to localize Helpshift according to your application's language, please look at the [setSDKLanguage API](https://developers.helpshift.com/ios/i18n/#set-language).